# Convert rows into columns using pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my table:

```
CaseID                                AttributeName  AttributeValue
03E07546-9C10-4399-B840-04F9CE211FB8  Case Title     deepa04
03E07546-9C10-4399-B840-04F9CE211FB8  Body Part      hand
03E07546-9C10-4399-B840-04F9CE211FB8  Diagnosis      123
E999866E-E8BE-4442-8A87-C419D482022E  Case Title     deep_case
E999866E-E8BE-4442-8A87-C419D482022E  Body Part      leg
E999866E-E8BE-4442-8A87-C419D482022E  Diagnosis      123
```

I need to convert this into:

```
CaseID                                Case Title  Body Part  Diagnosis
03E07546-9C10-4399-B840-04F9CE211FB8  deepa04     hand       123
E999866E-E8BE-4442-8A87-C419D482022E  deep_case   leg        123
```

How can I achieve this using dynamic pivot functions in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: check this link http://weblogs.asp.net/salimfayad/archive/2008/01/30/rows-to-columns.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try tihis:

```
select CaseID  ,   [Case Title],[Body Part],  Diagnosis
from <your_table>
PIVOT (MAX(AttributeValue) FOR AttributeName IN 
([Case Title],[Body Part],  Diagnosis)) P
```

**Edit1:**      If column Names are Dynamic You could do this

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(AttributeName) 
                    from <your_table>
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT CaseID  , ' + @cols + ' from t_case
             pivot 
            (
                MAX(AttributeValue)
                for AttributeName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
print(@query)
execute(@query)
```

Comment: but Case Title,Body Part,Diagnosis  are dynamic values,in that case what we do?

Comment: Then we can do a dynamic pivot query

Comment: The column name we can store in a variable and the use  it in the query

Comment: @Jeffreykalampukattussery: I have updated my answer , Plz check it

Comment: thanks for that joe,but [Body Part],[Case Title],[Diagnosis],[DOB],[History],[Keywords],[Modality],[Sex] from t_case getting error "Invalid object name 't_case'." t_case is a temperory table,does dat making the error

Comment: @Jeffreykalampukattussery: t_case should be replaced with your table .

Comment: ya i did like that, i have changed my table name into t_case

Comment: @Jeffreykalampukattussery: t_case should be replaced with your table name.. I have updated my answer plz check

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
select P.CaseID, P.[Case Title], P.[Body Part], P.Diagnosis
from (
     select CaseID, AttributeName, AttributeValue
     from YourTable
     ) as T
pivot (
      min(AttributeValue) 
      for AttributeName in ([Case Title], [Body Part], [Diagnosis])
      ) as P
```

Comment: but Case Title,Body Part,Diagnosis  are dynamic values,in that case what we do?